# Onclick select specific set of JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, loops, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a JSON object, like so:

```
{
  "workouts":
  [
    {
      "title": "Full Body",
      "exercises":
      [
        {
          "name": "Push Ups",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Squats",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Running in Place",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "God Legs",
      "exercises":
      [
        {
          "name": "Running in Place (High Knees)",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Squats",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Clams",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "title": "Morning Stretch",
      "exercises":
      [
        {
          "name": "Downward Dog",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Face Plant",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        },
        {
          "name": "Warrior",
          "duration": 3,
          "break": 3
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looping through this data to create a list of cards dynamically. I would like to make it so that when a card is tapped/clicked, the information relative to that specific data set is displayed/accessed.

**EXAMPLE** if I tap the card with the "Full Body" title, I would like a list to be displayed containing only the exercises in the "Full Body" exercises array, which should be: Push Ups, 3, 3 - Squats, 3, 3 - Running in Place 3, 3.

I am using Firebase to host my data on the real time database.

HTML:

```
<!--LIST THAT THE DYNAMICALLY GENERATED CARDS ARE APPENDED TO-->
<ul id="cardList" class="cards"></ul>

<!--MARKUP FOR THE CARDS, USED IN THE JSON FOR LOOP-->
<li>
  <div class='card' onclick='selectWorkout(this)'>
    <a class='startIt' href='timer.html'>
      <div class='cardInfo'>
         <h3>Full Body</h3>
         <p>10 min.</p>
       </div>
    </a>
    <a class='cardOptions' href='overview.html'>
      <p>Options</p>
    </a>
  </div>
</li>
```

JavaScript:

```
// Initialize Firebase.
firebase.initializeApp(config);
// Reference data.
var dbRef = firebase.database().ref().child("workouts");
// Sync with Firebase in real time.
dbRef.on("value", snap =>
{
  var workouts = snap.val();

  for (var i = 0;  i < workouts.length; i++) // WORKS GREAT.
  {
    //display.innerHTML = exercises[0].name;
    //$("#cardList").append(exercises[i].title);
    var routine = workouts[i].title;

    $("#cardList").append("<li><div class='card'><a class='startIt' href='#' onclick='selectWorkout(this)'>\n\
    <div class='cardInfo'><h3>" + routine + "</h3><p>10 min.</p>\n\
    </div></a><a class='cardOptions' href='overview.html'>\n\
    <div id='options'><p>Options</p></div></a></div></li>"); // ALL GOOD.
  }

  function selectWorkout(this) // NOT ONLY DOES NOT ACHIEVE DESIRED GOAL, BREAKS ENTIRE FUNCTION.
  {
    var selected = workouts[this].exercises;
    $("#cardList").append(selected);
  }
});
```

I think I am doing, as usual, something stupid: It would seem "this" is not allowed in the workouts square brackets, but how do I get a specific set of data otherwise?

Comment: What does this refer to in the selectWorkout context? 
What you can do is pass the name of the exercise to the onclick event instead of passing `this` then in your select workout function, loop through the json and find which object has the value of property exercise to be whether full body or whatever was passed as an argument to the function

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, you can't pass in `this` as a parameter name - it's a reserved word. In general I'd try to avoid using `this` in javascript if you can - it's really tricky.

A more robust way to do this is to create your card HTML as a separate jQuery object and add a specific clickhandler, like this:

```
var routine = workouts[i].title;

//create card element
var $card = ("<li><div class='card'><button class='startIt'><div class='cardInfo'><h3>" + routine + "</h3><p>10 min.</p></div></a><a class='cardOptions' href='overview.html'>   <div id='options'><p>Options</p></div></button></div></li>");

//add click handler
$card.find("button.startIt").on("click", function() {
    selectWorkout( workouts[i] );
});

//put card on the page
$("#cardList").append($card);
```

And then

function selectWorkout(workout) 
  {
    var selected = workout.exercises;

```
//not sure what you're trying to do here??
$("#cardList").append(selected);
```

}

You may notice that I've changed your `<a href='#'>` into a `<button>` - generally better for accessibility!

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it breaks and the console gives me the error Uncaught TypeError: $card.find is not a function.